# Proving $C_0^1(\Omega)$ is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

Hi I am trying to work on the following problem:

(a) $C_0^1(\Omega)$ is dense in $L_2(\Omega)$

(b) $C_0^1(\Omega)$ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

(c) Explain why $C_0^1(\Omega)$ is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$.

I know how to do (a) and (b) but I couldn't find how to solve (c). Any help would greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

So By following the comments given below I got

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n^2x^2,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,0\le x\le\frac{1}{n}\\1,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{1}{n}\le x\le 1-\frac{1}{n}\\n^2x^2,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,1-\frac{1}{n}\le x\le 1\end{cases}$$

Clearly $f_n(x)\to 1$ but $f(x)=1\not\in C_0^1(\Omega)$ where as $f_n(x)\in C_0^1$, therefore $C_0^1(\Omega)$ is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$.

I still have a doubt about the fact that is $f_n(x)$ in $C_0^1(\Omega)$, since the derivative is not continuous anymore.

Comment: The constant functions are in the closure of $C_0^1(\Omega)$ ? (for what norm ?)

Comment: @user1952009 I did not get what you said. Very sorry

Comment: Is there a sequence $f_n \in C_0^1(\Omega)$ converging to $f(x) =1$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 what about $f_n=1+\frac{x}{n}$

Comment: Take $\Omega= [0,1]$. Then $f_n$ is not in $C_0^1(\Omega)$ which is the set of functions in $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ whose support is $\subseteq  \Omega$

Comment: So I repeat my hint : $f(x) = 1$ is in $H^1([0,1])$. Can you find a sequence $f_n \in C_0^1([0,1])$ such that $\|f-f_n\|_{H^1} \to 0$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 If I can find such a series then doesn't it mean it is dense? But it is not dense, right?

Comment: Can you find such a sequence ? ${}{}$

Comment: @user1952009 So far I couldn't find any sequence like that, but even if I don't find any sequence like that, would that be enough to prove in general that it is not dense.? Again thanks a lot.

Comment: If you can prove that any such sequence exists, yes of course.

Comment: Let $g_n(x) = 1_{x \in [1/n,1-1/n]}$. Then $g_n \to 1$ in $L^2([0,1])$, right ? But it doesn't work in $H^1$ because $g_n$ is not differentiable. So we take $f_n(x) = 1_{x \in [1/n,1-1/n]}+ (1-n^2 x^2) \, 1_{x \in [0,1/n]}+ (1-n^2(1-x)^2)\, 1_{x \in [1-1/n,1]}$. But again we have a problem : $f_n'(x) = 
 2x n \, 1_{x \in [0,1/n]}- 2(1-x) n \, 1_{x \in [1-1/n,1]}$ and hence $\|f_n\|_{H^1} \to \infty$. Right ??

Comment: @user1952009 But $f_n\not\in C_0^1([0,1])$

Comment: Because of a typo. Of course I meant add a smooth transition to $1_{x \in [1/n,1-1/n]}$ such that it is in $C^1_0([0,1])$. As I said, the problem is that $\|f_n\|_{H^1} \to \infty$

Comment: @user1952009: Are you sure about the convergence to infinity? Seems the $L^2$ norm of $f_n'$ is $O(1/\sqrt{n})$, as in $\sqrt{n^2·(1/n)^3}$.

Comment: The example might still work if one tries a different limit function like $f(x)=x^{2/3}$ with $L^2$ integrable derivative $f'(x)=\frac23x^{-1/3}$.

Comment: Yes I'm sure the $L^2$ norm of $n 1_{x \in [0,1/n]}$ is $\sqrt{n}$. And for having $f_n(0) = 0, f_n(1/n) = 1$ we need $f_n'(x) \approx n$ on $[0,1/n]$.

Comment: @user1952009 I wrote the solution according to your comments. Could you please check it.

Comment: You meant $f_n(x) = 1- (1-n x)^2$ on $[0,1/n]$, $f_n(x) = 1$ on $[1/n,1-1/n]$ Which is $C^1_0([0,1])$.

Comment: Moreover, that $\|f_n'\|_{L^2}$ diverges is not enough. You need to show that for any sequence $g_n \in C_0^1([0,1]$ such that $g_n(x) = 1$ on $[1/n,1-1/n]$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\|g_n'\|_{L^2}= \infty$

Answer (score 1):

You can check that via looking at the trace. Let $D$ denote the closure of $C_0^1(0,1)$ in $H^1(0,1)$. By definition, the trace of $u \in C_0^1(0,1)$ is zero at both end points. Moreover, it is continuous. Hence, the trace of any function in $D$ is $0$. However, there are functions in $H^1(0,1)$ with non-zero trace, e.g., $x \mapsto 1$.

Answer (score -2):

Note: f(x) = 1 has compact support, so this entire example is invalid.

Comment: What?  No, it doesn't.  ($\Omega$ is usually assumed open, and we mean "compact support inside $\Omega$").  The $[0,1]$ example in comments should have been $(0,1)$.