# Proving that $\{\varphi\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)\,: \varphi(b) = 0\}$ is dense in $\{u\in H^1(\Omega)\,:\, u(b) = 0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

**Notation**

> Given $\Omega :=(a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}$ a bounded open interval, let us define the Sobolev spaces $H^1(\Omega):=\{v\in L^2(\Omega)\,: \, v'\in L^2(\Omega)\}$,  $H_0^1(\Omega):=\{v\in H^1(\Omega): v(a) = v(b)= 0\}$. Further let $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ denote respectively the smooth functions on $\Omega$ in the former case and those who have compact support in the latter case.

**Background**

> Additionaly, we define a subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$ with values that vanishes in the right boundary  $H_R^1(\Omega):=\{u\in H^1(\Omega)\,:\, u(b) = 0\}$ and $S = \{\varphi\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)\,: \varphi(b) = 0\}$. **The overall objective is to prove that $S$ is dense in $H_R^1(\Omega)$**.

There are some previous results that i know

> **Lemma 1.** $C_0^{\infty}(\Omega) $ is dense in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ with respecto to the norm $\|v\|_{1,\Omega} = 
>  \int_\Omega v^2$ for $v\in H^1(\Omega)$.

> **Theorem 8.2** (Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential
> Equations, by Haim Brezis)
> $$H^1(\Omega)\hookrightarrow C(\overline\Omega)$$
> In other words, for all $v\in H^1(\Omega)$ there exists $u\in C(\overline\Omega)$ such that $u = v$ almost everywhere and
> $$\int_x^yv'(t) \text{d}t = u(y)-u(x),\,\,\forall x,y\in \overline \Omega $$

**What i've tried so far**

Remark: The objective is to prove that $S$ is dense in $H_R^1(\Omega)$. Let $v\in H_R^1(\Omega)$, is desired to build a sequence $\{\psi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements in $S$ such that

\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty} \|v-\psi_n\|_{1,\Omega} = 0
\end{align*}

I've tried two different things:

1. I first aimed to build $\{\psi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ from a sequence in $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ that converges to some extension $u$ of $v$ that lies in $H_0^1(\Omega)$. So far i've tried
   \begin{align*}
   u(t) = \begin{cases}v(t) & t\in \overline \Omega, t\neq a\\ 0 & t = a\end{cases}
   \end{align*}
   With this definition might be clear that $u$ vanishes in both extreme values of $\overline\Omega$. However, this function is not necessarily continuous for $t = a$. Is there a way to ensure that this extension is in $H_0^1(\Omega)$?
2. It is clear that $H_0^1(\Omega)\subseteq H_R^1(\Omega)\subseteq H^1(\Omega)$ and $C_0^{\infty}\subseteq S$. If there's a subspace $R$ of $H_R^1(\Omega)$ that allows us to write $H_R^1(\Omega) = H_0^1(\Omega) + R$,  $v$ can be decomposed as $v = v_0 + v_R$, where we can use Lemma 1, to show that there is a sequence of elements in $C_0^{\infty}$ converging to $v_0$, and then construct the desired sequence of elements in $S$. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to detect which space is the right one to perform this decomposition.

Any ideas, suggestions or corrections are well-received.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your definition of the space $H^1_0$ makes no sense. $L^p$ spaces are equivalence classes and so using point values to define a subset of them is not a well-defined operation. The correct way to define them is that the space $H^1_0$ is simply the completion of $C_c^\infty$ functions in the $H^1$ norm. Same for $H^1_R$. So there is nothing to prove, i.e., the property you are trying to prove follows from the definition of the spaces.

Comment: @almosteverywhere in 1d $H^1$ continuously embeds into continuous functions. Also the condition $\phi(b)=0$ can be understand in the sense of traces, which is perfectly valid even in higher dimensions.

Comment: @daw In one dimension yes. But in general it does not embed. I should have probably said it is a definition that does not generalise easily rather than does not make sense. Of course you can use traces but the first step to defining $H^1_0$ is to define it as the completion of $C_c^\infty$. After that you realise you can extend the trace operator in a sensible manner and setting the trace to be zero is the same as looking at the completion.

Comment: The definition of $H^1_R$ as in the OP is the only way to define this space, where boundary condition is meant in the sense of traces. It does generalize, at least for Lipschitz domains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $C_0^1(\Omega)$ is not dense in $H^1(\Omega)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244142/proving-c-01-omega-is-not-dense-in-h1-omega)

Comment: @almosteverywhere the other question is unrelated. There the density is not true, here the claim is true.

Comment: @daw One can also define $H^1_R$ by looking at the completion of smooth functions that are $0$ on the right side, i.e. the completion of $C^\infty_c([a,b))$.

Comment: @daw one of the subquestions in the other answer seems to answer this; namely part (b).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of the proof.

Let $u\in H^1_R$.
Take $h>0$ and define the translation
$$
u_h(x) = u(x+h)  \quad x \in (a,b),
$$
where we set $u(x)=0$ for $x\ge b$.
Then $u_h\in H^1_R$ and $u_h\to u$ in $H^1$ for $h\searrow 0$.

Now we do a mollification with the standard kernel, $\phi_\epsilon = \rho_\epsilon \ast u_h$. For $\epsilon\in (0,h)$, we have $\phi_\epsilon \in S$, and $\phi_\epsilon \to u_h$ for $\epsilon \searrow 0$.